# JSON string should be logged as structured data, not just as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I expect that the JSON string should be logged as structured data, not just as a string.

like this

```cs
var data = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}";
using (LogContext.PushProperty("data", data))
{
   _logger.LogInformation("balabala");
}
// output: {"@t":"2024-01-17T02:58:00.6737234Z","@m":"balabala","@i":"089ce129","data":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","$type":"xxxx"}}
```

I attempted to convert the JSON into a dictionary.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have random stuff that might be valid JSON, or a JSON object from a parser. I believe there are libs about that will cause a JSON object tree to be rendered in structured format by representing it as structured data in the LogEvent at the point of capture. In general any formatter that's rendering a random string will take care to escape embedded JSON correctly - that's the wrong place/time to go treating it as a hierarchical structure.

Comment: If you pass Serilog the whole original object (rather than a JSON string) it will serialize it correctly.

Comment: ... if you pass `true` as a third argument to switch destructureObjects on

Answer (score 0):

> JSON string should be logged as structured data, not just as a string
>
> I attempted to convert the JSON into a dictionary.
>
> Is there a way to do this?

Yeah according to your scenario and requirement, yes, you can achieve this by converting the JSON string into a dictionary and then logging it as structured data.
You can use a popular library like `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize the JSON string into a dictionary and then log the dictionary as structured data.

In order to implement that you can do as following:

First of all, you need to convert the JSON `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString)`  string into a dictionary.
Then , the `LogContext.PushProperty` method is then used to push the data property along with its dictionary value onto the logging context. A
The last parameter (true) indicates that the value should be rendered as structured data.

Let's have a look in practice:

```
var jsonData = "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}";

var dataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonData);

using (LogContext.PushProperty("data", dataDictionary, true))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("balabala");
}
```

Alternatively, you even can use `JObject.Parse(jsonData)` using `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

```
var parsedData = JObject.Parse(jsonData);

using (LogContext.PushProperty("data", parsedData))
{
    _logger.LogInformation("balabala");
}
```

**Note:** If you have a strongly typed representation of the JSON data, use it directly instead of parsing into a dictionary. This provides better type safety and potential performance benefits. In addition, for complex scenarios, you can create custom serializers to fine-tune the output format.